# Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found

Tags: equation-solving

The Solve function sometimes gives solutions but sometime does not. For example, the first code gives the solutions, however, the second one gives errors.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code

```
Solve[Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] == 0 && Sin[b - a] + Sin[b] == 0 && Sin[-a] + Sin[-b] == 0, {a, b}]

Solve[Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] + Sin[a - d] == 0 && Sin[b - a] + Sin[b] + Sin[b - d] == 0 && Sin[-a] + Sin[-b] - Sin[-d] == 0 && Sin[d - a] + Sin[d - b] == 0, {a, b, d}]
```

Could anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the title suggests: "use Reduce ..." instead of `Solve`. Or have you tried it already? (1 min later) OH while I was typing this the title got changed.

Comment: @Syed Ah yes I just tried and it works! Why is that and how do I determine when to use Solve and when to use Reduce? (I was thinking of whether the title is too long so I changed it ;)

Comment: Solve gives generic solutions that are true for all parameters. Reduce tries to find all solutions, even those that are only true for some parameter values.

Comment: @DanielHuber Here the equations do not have parameters, does this mean Reduce gives all the solutions?

Comment: Here we have also have the problem that inverse functions are multivalued. Solve can not solve the second equation. But Reduce, which is more powerful, can.

Comment: There is also `Solve[eqns, vars, Method -> Reduce]` which is more powerful than `Solve` without the option, but still less powerful than `Reduce`.